# Why can only admin user access the print version of a view?

Tags: views

I have installed the [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module and I have a view named *XXX* and the admin can access to the print version of the *XXX* view with the path `/printpdf/XXX`.

If I change the user to other user without admin permission, I get this message

> Access denied
>
> You are not authorized to access this page.

I don't know how to allow non admin users to access the print version of a view.

I set this permissions for non admin users like so:

- Bypass views access control.
- Access the printer-friendly page.

But such user still does not have access to the print version of a view.

Is there a way to achieve the access with non admin users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PDF version (print_pdf)

Head over to your "permissions" page, located at `admin/people/permissions`. Then in the field near the top, which says "Filter list", just type "pdf".

That'll give you a narrowed down list of all permissions that have "pdf" in their description. One of them is "Access the PDF version", which is the permission you want to fine tune to fit your requirements. And each of them is preceded by a line, in bold, which shows the name of the module the permission is related to.

The "narrowed down" list in my case shows only 2 permissions (the 2nd one is because I have 1 other module enabled that also has a PDF-related permission). So hard to not catch the one I should be looking for, right?

## Printer friendly pages (print) and send by eMail (print_mail)

`print_pdf` is one of the sub-modules of the [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module. Other submodules of it are `print` (= Printer friendly pages) and `print_mail` (send by eMail). Some more details about those sub-modules:

- The `print` submodule has a similar permission, which is "**Access the printer-friendly page**" (= View the printer-friendly pages and the links to them in the original pages).
- The `print_mail` submodule has a similar permission, which is "**Send by email**" (= Provides the ability to send pages by email and the links to them in the original pages). **Attention**: if you want to use this eMail feature, make sure you do not (repeat NOT) allow that for anonymous users. Because if you do allow that, you open up a huge spamming opportunity for your anonymous users ... imagine a spammer using it enters an eMail Id of somebody that the spammer wants to spam ... typically with a message content that is 100% spam, instead of what you'd expect (something like "hey, have a look at this interesting URL" ... But: the message will arrive with something like "from = an eMail id related to your website".

**PS**: Permission "Bypass views access control" should be used carefully (do not grant it to anybody unless you really have a need for it ... in this case it does not seem to be needed to solve your access issue).

Answer (score 5):

I have a help at this moment from a friend. The solution is simple, just search the permission *Access the PDF version* in admin/people/permissions and set the permission to the users. The problem was that the permission page is too long and if you search for *print* you will never find *Access the PDF version` permission*

[image: screenshot]